# How to find $R_{ll}$ of the orthogonal matrix R?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I get that $R_{kk}=\sqrt{1-s^2}$ but for $ R_{ll} $ I need to find $R_{lk} $ which is not given, so I am wondering how to find it? Or, is there a relation between $R_{kl} $ and $R_{lk} $ which I am missing?

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: $R^TR=I$... does it help?

Comment: yes I did this, but how does this help?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Lower_dimensions for two forms of orthogonal  matrices - rotation and reflection..

Comment: Could you please write this as an answer as I cannot see it(with the Rll,Rlk notation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two forms of orthogonal $2 \times 2$ matrices

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix}\text{ (rotation), }\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & -\cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix}\text{ (reflection)}$$

From this we can see what are possible relations between different entries of  the orthogonal matrix. In the conditions of the task is that both diagonal entries are positive so they have to have the same sign... $(R_{kk}=R_{ll}$ and $R_{kl}=-R_{lk})$ ...